# Relationship between Arithmetic Mean(AM), Geometric Mean(GM) and Harmonic mean(HM)

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics

Does the relationship $GM^2 = AM * HM$ hold when the number of elements is greater than $2$ ($3$ or more elements). It doesn't seem to work for some examples that I have chosen randomly, like the numbers $2$, $5$ and $9$, which gives $57.7 = 59$, a gap of $1.3$. Too large to be attributed to errors related to using floating point numbers.

Does it only work when having two elements?

Comment: You have already found counter examples, so what is the question?

Comment: I guess I just want to make sure(even though I think it is very unlikely) that the counterexamples I found are not caused by the way computers handle real numbers(as floating point numbers). I have found some pages where the formula is stated first, then demonstrated afterwards using an example of two numbers, which is confusing if it only works for two number. In which case that should have been pointed out in the beginning.

Comment: @hamidbaroudi the reason for this relationship with two numbers is that $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}\cdot\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{(a+b)ab}{a+b} = ab$. Try to do this with three numbers -- you will see that it doesn't work in the same way then

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to work the same way, it is true that as you try to simplify it, you get stuck. I thought there might be some workaround to simplify it more, but I guess that identity doesn't generalize for $n\ge3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the case of $n=2$ values' AM, GM and HM is special. (The value $n=1$ is even more special!) In general, you're comparing $(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i)^{2/n}$ to $\frac{\sum_ix_i}{\sum_j1/x_j}=\frac{\sum_ix_i}{\sum_j\prod_{k\ne j}x_k}\prod_kx_k$. When $n=2$, the LHS's exponent is $1$, and the RHS has denominator $\sum_jx_j$. But for $n\ge3$, the denominator is of degree $n-1\ge2$, so you won't get the identity you want.

Comment: Is there a general formula for the relationship between the three types of means of any number of elements?

Comment: @hamidbaroudi Not in the form of an equation, no. There are some inequalities, such as $\operatorname{AM}\ge\operatorname{GM}\ge\operatorname{HM}$.